# Delete all cards(sources) from stripe, Laravel stripe

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier, stripes

Wanted to delete all the cards (sources) from the stripe account.
Unable to find any API from documentation to delete the existing cards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Stripe API to retrieve a list of all sources for the customer, and then loop through the list to delete each source using its unique identifier.

```
use Stripe\Stripe;
use Stripe\Customer;  

Stripe::setApiKey('YOUR_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY');    
// Retrieve the customer by its ID
$customer = Customer::retrieve('CUSTOMER_ID');    
// Retrieve a list of all sources for the customer
$sources = $customer->sources->all(['object' => 'card']);    
// Loop through each source and delete it
foreach($sources->data as $source) {
    $source->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I already got a solution to use the below piece of code to delete all cards from the customer.

```
$stripe_secret = env('STRIPE_SECRET');
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
            $stripe_secret
        );
    
        $sources = $stripe->customers->allSources(
            $customerId,
            ['object' => 'card']
        );
        foreach ($sources as $source) {
            $stripe->customers->deleteSource(
                $customerId,
                $source->id,
                []
            );
        }
```